# Need help with multiple URL setup on local CF9/Jrun install

Tags: url, coldfusion, mapping, coldfusion-9, jrun

I am running the ColdFusion 9 Developer edition on my local Windows XP machine. I've installed it with the embedded web server, which I believe is JRun.

Right now, I can only access web pages at 127.0.0.1:8500/whatever - with all of my apps being placed within separate directories, i.e.: 127.0.0.1:8500/app1, 127.0.0.1:8500/app2, etc.

I want to set it up so that I can access each app at:  app1.mylocalserver.com, app2.mylocalserver.com, etc.

I have edited the hosts file so that these domains will be routed to my local machine. But how do I get CF9/Jrun to recognize these urls and handle them correctly? I have been playing with the WEB-INF/jrun-web.xml file but that seems to handle virtual file mappings only.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Gary

Comment: Download and use Apache VirtualHosts.  Use the wsconfig tool in CF to use Apache.  Then set up virtual hosts in Apache to point to your different sites.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't suggest using the built in web server.  Can't you install Apache or use IIS?

Comment: Use IIS. however on XP you can only use one IIS website at a time. Very annoying. This tool helped me before: http://www.jetstat.com/iisadmin/ Or else upgrade to Win7 and use proper bindings! :)

Comment: Vista ships with IIS 7 (maybe 7.5?) which can handle multiple sites as well.  I usually set up a hosts entry which is my live domain name without the TLD (ie: http://cfsilence.com becomes http://cfsilence/ on dev machine) and set up the IIS site with that host name.

Of course all of this depends on what OS the original poster is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

if you changed it so those names are directed to your IP, shouldn't you just be able to go into site management and reference it there?

I use the built in one as well (for CF 9 on XP) and so far i haven't had an issue with it (been using it this way for over a year)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea to configure multiple URL. In IIS, it's simple to way configure multiple URL with different ports or binding different IP address.