# ColdFusion 9 server url rewrites and subfolders

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting, coldfusion-9, subdirectory

I've installed the coldfusion 9 server locally (the development standalone edition)

I'm trying to get the url rewriting to work, but I don't know what file it's reading (htaccess or web.config), though I'm guessing it's the later if it is reading it at all.

Any idea how to set up the server to use local(to subfolder) rewrite rules?

Comment: Are you using Apache or IIS or neither?  To get URL rewriting you'll need to install Apache or IIS and then configure them accordingly (using htaccess or web.config respectively). If you're *just* using the standalone CF with the built-in webserver you won't be able to get URL rewrites to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been stated on StackOverflow [in other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588350/need-help-with-multiple-url-setup-on-local-cf9-jrun-install), the built-in webserver is primarily for convenience. To take full advantage of production-grade webserver configuration options (like mod_rewrite), your best bet is to install IIS or Apache.

Having said that, the sparse documentation on the built-in webserver can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd8.html).

Comment: Got it... trying the built-in IIS 7. But I'm having issues with CF9 running on it, so I'll see if the reinstall works.